# GitHub consistently displays directories in .gitignore file

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I've been working with GitHub for years, but this is a new issue. My project (https://github.com/MisterMorse/abbas-tables-node-express-api) keeps displaying JetBrains fluff despite my .gitignore file marking it. The file says:

.idea/

.idea

idea/

idea

/.idea/

/.idea

/idea/

/idea

But the folder is ALWAYS displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Trying to ignore stuff that is already tracked, probably? That is not gonna fly.

Comment: GitHub doesn't care about your `.gitignore` file; that's only meaningful to `git`, and it doesn't influence how `git` treats files that have already been added to your repository (it just prevents `git` from noticing *untracked* files). If GitHub is showing those directories, it suggests you have added files in those directories to your repository.

Comment: In your case : you probably want to run `git rm -r --cached .idea/`, and then `git commit --amend` to modify the existing commit. You will then have to run `git push --force` to update your github's repo with a history whuch contains only the correct content.

Comment: Thanks, guys. I rarely post because I don't want to look lazy if answers already exist, but I don't always know just what to look for.